# New columns in data.frame don't retain POSIXct class

Tags: r, dataframe, class

I spent almost two days to find the reason of an error occuirring - probably trivial for many, but I cannot figure out the reason for that and I am thankful for help:

When I create a new data.frame and add columns with a specific class (POSIXct) using `...$...` syntax, it works nicely ("p" columns in code below, they become class *P*OSIXct as intended).

However, if I do the same using the `...[..., ...]` syntax, POSIXct class is lost upon assignment ("n" columns in code below, since they become unintendedly class *n*umeric).

Even after setting class explicitely, it remains numeric using the `...[..., ...]` syntax, but not using the `...$....` syntax..

What is the reasoning behind this behaviour? Obviously I have found a workaround, but it is more convenient to use vectors of column names, and I am afraid that I miss sth. very basic but cannot figure out what, or where to look by which keywords.

**Basically I need to access the columns by a variable and then assign class and data.**

```
rm(dfDummy)  # just make sure there is no residual old data/columns leftover
dfDummy <- data.frame(a = 1:10, dummy = dummy)
dfDummy$p <- as.POSIXct(NA)
dfDummy$p.rep <- as.POSIXct(rep(NA, 10))
dfDummy[ , c("n1", "n2")] <- as.POSIXct(NA)
dfDummy[ , c("n1.rep", "n2.rep")] <- as.POSIXct(rep(NA, 10))
sapply(X = c("p", "p.rep", "n1", "n2", "n1.rep", "n2.rep"), function(x) class(dfDummy[, x]))
# even after setting the class explicitely, it remains "numeric" - what is wrong?
class(dfDummy[ , c("n1", "n2", "n1.rep", "n2.rep")]) <- c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
sapply(X = c("p", "p.rep", "n1", "n2", "n1.rep", "n2.rep"), function(x) class(dfDummy[, x]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing really to do with using `$` or `[`, except when using `$` a single column is being assigned and when you're using `[` multiple columns are.

Rather when you assign into multiple columns the POSIXct vector is being recycled and simplified into a matrix - and matrices can't hold class POSIXct.

If you instead pass a list, it will work:

```
dfDummy[ , c("n1.rep", "n2.rep")] <- list(as.POSIXct(NA))

lapply(dfDummy[ , c("n1.rep", "n2.rep")], class)

$n1.rep
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$n2.rep
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```